# Firebase Realtime with Cloud Functions delete limit and usage cost

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a large node in Realtime Database that I want to delete everyday using Cloud Functions schedule.

Is there a limit on how much data I can delete using Cloud Functions on Realtime Database? And where can I find the cost for delete?

I've read the billing doc ([link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/billing)) but I'm not sure where it is mentioned about delete cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start by adding [this link](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).

Combining the informations in your link and in this one I've added, the answer is: no, you'll not be billed if you just delete data. The important information here is: if you just delete it. You will still be billed if, before you delete it, you download it. In other words, if you get the reference to a node in your code, and then you just perform a `remove(ref)`, you won't be billed.

There is a remote possibility that you can be billed for a huge CPU consumption. This could happen if the node you're deleting is really big, but you can estimate this by testing it out and checking the "Usage" tab in your Firebase console, under the voice "Load". If the load for a testing delete is low, you're good and you won't be billed.